# run-time compiled class cannot implement interface - Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn from Sep 2012. I'm trying to create instance of a class from file. Problem is that the class is implementing and overriding some methods. When I try to run a run-time compile a get errors like:

```
error CS0122: 'GameObject' is inaccessible due to its protection level  Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Diagnostic
error CS0115: 'rotate(float)': no suitable method found to override Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.Diagnostic
```

It looks like class doesn't see interface and overriding functions. But my Compilation looks:

```
var comp = Compilation.Create("Test.dll"
            , syntaxTrees: new[] { syntaxTree }
            , references: new[] { 
                MetadataFileReference.CreateAssemblyReference("mscorlib"),
                new MetadataFileReference(typeof(Game.IGameObjectInterface).Assembly.Location),
                new MetadataFileReference(typeof(Team).Assembly.Location),
                new MetadataFileReference(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
                new MetadataFileReference(typeof(LinkedList<>).Assembly.Location),

            }
            , options: new CompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
            );
```

Reference on the interface is added.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT GameObject

```
abstract class GameObject: IGameObject {
    protected string name;
    protected Entity entity;
       .
       .
       .
    //Look here create file load file
    static GameObject() {
        gameActionsPermitions = new Dictionary<string, List<IStaticGameObject>>();
        gameActions = new Dictionary<string, IGameAction>();
        IGameAction o = (IGameAction)System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("Strategy.GroupControl.Game_Objects.GameActions.Produce");
        gameActions.Add(o.getName(), o);
        gameActionsPermitions.Add(o.getName(), new List<IStaticGameObject>());
    }

       .
       .
       .


    public abstract void rotate(float f);
    public abstract void nonActiveRotate(float f);
    protected abstract void onDisplayed();


       .
       .
       .

    }
```

And inteface IGameObject

```
interface IGameObject{
    void rotate(float f);
    void nonActiveRotate(float f);
    void changeVisible(bool visible);
    string getName();
    string getMesh();
    bool tryExecute(string executingAction);

    Team Team { get; set; }

}
```

And function from file is

```
public override void rotate(float f) {
        tryExecute("Produce");
        sceneNode.Roll(new Mogre.Degree((float)(mFlySpeed * 0.5 *f)));
        //position in LinkedList now moving
        if (!mFlying) {
            if (nextLocation()) {
                mFlying = true;
                mDestination = circularPositions.First.Value; //get the next destination.
                prepareNextPosition();
                //update the direction and the distance
                mDirection = mDestination - sceneNode.Position;
                mDistance = mDirection.Normalise();
            } else {
            }//nothing to do so stay in position    
        } else {
            double move = mFlySpeed * f;
            mDistance -= move;
            if (mDistance <= .0f) { //reach destination
                travelledInvisible = 0;
                sceneNode.Position = mDestination;
                mDirection = Mogre.Vector3.ZERO;
                mFlying = false;
            } else {
                sceneNode.Translate(mDirection * (float)move);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT2:

file with class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Mogre;
using Strategy.TeamControl;



namespace Strategy.GroupControl.Game_Objects.StaticGameObjectBox {
class Planet : GameObject {

    protected double mDistance = 0.0f; //distance to positoin
    protected Mogre.Vector3 mDirection = Mogre.Vector3.ZERO;   // The direction the object is moving

    protected bool mFlying = false; //bool to detect if object walking or stay
    protected double mFlySpeed = 200f; //speed of planet

    protected double travelledInvisible;


    private static Random random = new Random();

    ///testing
    public Planet() {

    }
    public Planet(string s) {
        name = s;
    }
    //end

    public Planet(string name, string mesh, Team myTeam, Mogre.SceneManager manager, double distanceFromCenter, 
        Vector3 center, int circularNum = 30) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mesh = mesh;
        planetTeam = myTeam;
        this.manager = manager;

        //prepare list of positions
        circularPositions = calculatePositions(circularNum, distanceFromCenter,center);
        randomizeStartPosition(circularNum); // randomize start position
        mDestination = circularPositions.First();

        //Mogre inicialization of object
        entity = manager.CreateEntity(name, mesh);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rotating in visible mood, it means when planet is in active solar system
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="f">delay between frames</param>
    public override void rotate(float f) {
        tryExecute("Produce");
        sceneNode.Roll(new Mogre.Degree((float)(mFlySpeed * 0.5 *f)));
        //position in LinkedList now moving
        if (!mFlying) {
            if (nextLocation()) {
                mFlying = true;
                mDestination = circularPositions.First.Value; //get the next destination.
                prepareNextPosition();
                //update the direction and the distance
                mDirection = mDestination - sceneNode.Position;
                mDistance = mDirection.Normalise();
            } else {
            }//nothing to do so stay in position    
        } else {
            double move = mFlySpeed * f;
            mDistance -= move;
            if (mDistance <= .0f) { //reach destination
                travelledInvisible = 0;
                sceneNode.Position = mDestination;
                mDirection = Mogre.Vector3.ZERO;
                mFlying = false;
            } else {
                sceneNode.Translate(mDirection * (float)move);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function calculate moves in invisible mode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="f">delay between frames</param>
    public override void nonActiveRotate(float f) {
        tryExecute("Produce");
        if (!mFlying) {
            if (nextLocation()) {
                mFlying = true;
                mDestination = circularPositions.First.Value; //get the next destination.
                prepareNextPosition();
                mDistance = mDirection.Normalise();
            } else {
            }//nothing to do so stay in position    
        } else {
            double move = mFlySpeed * f;
            mDistance -= move;
            if (mDistance <= .0f) { //reach destination
                travelledInvisible = 0;
                mDirection = Mogre.Vector3.ZERO;
                mFlying = false;

            } else {
                travelledInvisible += move;
            }
        }
    }


    //own functions 

    /// <summary>
    /// Randomize starting position of planet
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="max">max of rotates</param>
    private  void randomizeStartPosition(int max) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getRandomNumber(max); i++) {
            prepareNextPosition();
        }
    }

    private static int getRandomNumber(int max) {
        return random.Next(max);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cyclic remove from LinkedList and add on the end
    /// </summary>
    private void prepareNextPosition() {
        var tmp = circularPositions.First; //save the node that held it
        circularPositions.RemoveFirst(); //remove that node from the front of the list
        circularPositions.AddLast(tmp);  //add it to the back of the list.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate posistion on circle represent as ngon
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="circularNum">Number of positions on circle</param>
    /// <param name="distanceFromCenter">radius on circle</param>
    /// <returns>linkedList with position on ngon (circle)</returns>
    private LinkedList<Mogre.Vector3> calculatePositions(int circularNum, double distanceFromCenter,Vector3 center) {
        var list = new LinkedList<Mogre.Vector3>();
        for (int i = 0; i < circularNum; i++) {
            double x = System.Math.Cos(i * 2 * System.Math.PI / circularNum) * distanceFromCenter;
            double y = System.Math.Sin(i * 2 * System.Math.PI / circularNum) * distanceFromCenter;
            list.AddFirst(new Mogre.Vector3((float)x + center.x, 0, (float)y)+ center.y);
        }

        return list;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The NextLocation() check if exist next location to move
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true ->exist / false -> not exist</returns>
    private bool nextLocation() {
        if (circularPositions.Count == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when object is displayed (invisible to visible)
    /// </summary>
    protected override void onDisplayed() {
        sceneNode.Position = mDestination;
        mFlying = false; //jump correction
    }
```

}
}

Comment: It looks like what you're doing wrong is using GameObject in a position that would illegally enlarge its accessibility domain, and you've marked a method as override when it doesn't override anything. There's not much more we can say about it without seeing `GameObject` and `rotate`.

Comment: I added a prototyp of `GameObject` with `rotate`.

Comment: And is the function in the file in a class that actually extends GameObject?

Comment: function from file added.

Comment: And is the accessibility domain of GameObject a superset of the accessibility domain of Planet? That is, you are not allowed to have a public class with an internal base class, or an internal class with a private base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look like standard compiler errors.

I suspect your `GameObject` class is not declared as `public`.  This will cause it to not be visible to the assembly you're creating via Roslyn, as it's compiling a new (separate) assembly from the one in which your types are defined.

If you make your types public, this error will likely go away.

Comment: And when I create this class `public` I must create every class which using this `public` class also `public`?

Comment: @wolen No - but any class used outside of that assembly should be public.

Comment: `var result = comp.Emit(moduleBuilder);` 
`Success = true`
Thanks